# For how long and how much should I accelerate?

Tags: vectors

Each second I can accelerate for a max. of 200 units.
I have to travel distance *d*.
Drag rate is 0.85.

I have to accelerate in such a way that when I stop accelerating I have enough momentum that object is stopped by drag at end of *d*

How to find time for which I should accelerate and amount of acceleration?

I know that my vector is from point A to point B so that equates to $\vec V=B-A$
I know that length of this vector is simply a vector magnitude $d = ||\vec V||$
And magnitude is equals to $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$
I know that on each passed second speed will be decreased by 0.85 so time x 0.85 x speed will give me actual speed at some point. For now that is all.

Looks like velocity from point at which I stop accelerating is calculated like $\vec v = \vec v_0 + \vec at$. From that I think I get $0 = \vec v_0 + (-0.85t)$ where $t$ I do not know.

Comment: How much effort have you spent trying to solve this problem on your own? (please share).

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add the upvote.

Comment: I will do some more tinkering regarding acceleration and I will do update once more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by drag rate.  As you wrote it, $\vec v = \vec {v_0} -0.85 t$, you have a constant deceleration of $0.85$ in whatever units you are using.  You also have a mismatch as one term is a vector and the other is a scalar, so you need to multiply the deceleration by $\frac {\vec v}{|\vec v|}$ to get a direction.  In that case (taking magnitudes) you have $d=v_0t-\frac 12\cdot 0.85 t^2$.  You reach zero velocity at $t=\frac {v_0}{0.85}$, so $d=\frac 1{2 \cdot 0.85}v_0^2$.  It is curious to have a fixed deceleration, but that may be how physics works in your game.

A more realistic version would have the drag proportional to the velocity, so $v=v_0-0.85v$.  Then the solution is a dying exponential and you never reach zero velocity.

Added:  If it is deceleration by a factor of $0.85$ per second, you have $v'(t)=-0.85v(t), v(t)=v_0\exp(-0.85 t), d=v_0/0.85.$  You never get to zero velocity, but the distance traveled does approach a limit.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I did a mistake. By rate I mean each second velocity should be multiplied by 0.85. This is how game simulates friction. For each turn previous velocity gets added to thrust * normalized vector. Velocity then is multiplied by 0.85 and final velocity is obtained.

Comment: Speeds in game are trimmed.